# What can you do with Opsource Cloud?

Tags: cloud

I've been trying to find information about cloud computing for a report. I found Opsource as an example but I don't know what is its intended uses and who might use this kind of service? What kind of work or business will use this kind of service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Opsource Cloud](http://www.opsourcecloud.net) is a cloud host.  A large corporation could outsource their cloud computing needs to them (paying by the hour or by usage.  They could set up an internal collaborative VPN, an e-Commerce site, service delivery or whatever.

OpSource cloud purports to provide the level of security, performance & control a business would need in order to move mission critical business components into the cloud.

Check out [the brochure](http://www.opsourcecloud.net/OpSourceCloud.pdf).